# Anticipation of Violent Gatherings

Tags: wisconsin

As we await the Rittenhouse verdict it is clear that this is a polarizing case and the governor has mobilized 500 National Guardsmen in anticipation of violence.

The verdict is expected to attract polarized crowds that officials perceive as having a proclivity for violence / destruction.

Pursuant to preventing violence: What tools are available to the Wisconson governor, besides having Guardsmen to strictly enforce a curfew?  Ideally, tools would not infringe on any rights of assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The Governor can have extra police as well as members of the National Guard in place prior to any verdict. Such Law Enforcement forces can be ready to suppress any violence, as well as enforcing a curfew. Ideally they would be briefed on appropriate levels of response, and the difference between protests and violence, and how and when to avoid escalation.

The Governor could appeal in advance to the public for calm and non-violence.  The Governor could speak with known leaders of various factions or groups who might be able to urge a non-violent response.

The Governor could perhaps restrict public acces to areas near the courthouse, but this might not be effective, and indeed might only serve to escalate things.

I am not sue if the Governor has the legal authority to decalre a temporary "no-weapons" zone in areas likely to be the scenes of violence, and even if that were legal, it might be a poor idea.